# Why Burp show Hebrew characters in gibberish when scanning a URL

Tags: character, hebrew, burp

While I was using Burp I noticed that it has problem to show Hebrew characters.

Reproduce:
Open Burp Professional, go to Dashboard and start a "New scan".
Enter the following URL (as an example):
https://blog.ravmilim.co.il

After couple of seconds it will show you the results in the Target tab:
[image]

In the "User options" tab I changed the Font and the "Character Sets" to UTF-8 but it still the same.

Any idea how it can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

simply change the font to Courier new.